# Swift Facebook Get Friends Graph Request Error

Tags: json, swift, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So, I am trying to get a list of all other facebook friends also connected on my app.

After doing an FBSDKgraphrequest, I get the right data (see below) and then convert it to an NSDictionary. The data looks like this:

```
{
    friends =     {
        data =         (
                        {
                id = 10154257515635281;
                name = "Hector Judd";
            },
                        {
                id = 151132798649181;
                name = "Arch Tester Dev";
            }
        );
        paging =         {
            cursors =             {
                after =  QVFIUndVRFZAINXhCSlAzdnNGeUUwTHdhamNpc3NFbjR2NjF4dk40N3ZAZAR2lNLXM0Q3BxLW90REVsaFk3aU13Um1Ca0NOd0ZAXN2gxaDF2emhYem9BMjhkMVl3;
                before = QVFIUlo2a1Q4UGhpWmY2SFNWbUtpMVcxZAnEtR01KSlUyeVEtMU9GbjNkRHp2bTFKY0VoVm5xX3dNLXEwMG5OY0Q0My0ZD;
            };
         };
        summary =         {
            "total_count" = 831;
        };
    };
    id = 10208811056967519;
}
```

I then try and unpack it with multiple if let statements, but end up getting the error: Segmentation fault 11. See code below.

```
func getFriends() {

    let parameters = ["fields": "friends"]

    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: parameters).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {

            print(error)

        } else {

            if let result = result as? NSDictionary {

                if let data = result["friends"] as? NSDictionary {

                    if let friendData = data["data"] as? NSArray {

                        for friend in friendData {

                            friendIds.append(friend["id"] as String)

                            print(friendIds)

                        }


                    }
                }

            }
        }

    })
}
```

I am relatively new to programming and am struggling to work out a good way to do this. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare your friendData variable as a NSDictionary in your Loop

```
   for friend in friends {
       if let friendData = friend as? NSDictionary {
              friendIds.append(friendData["id"] as! String)
       }
   }
```